# Is it “grammar error” or “grammatical error”?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

We say *“spelling error”*, which seems to imply it would be *“grammar error”* since both spelling and grammar are nouns, whereas grammatical is an adjective, but I can’t help think *“grammatical error”* is what I would say, and *feels* more correct. But it bothers me that the two phrases don’t have the same grammatical structure.

Similarly, I don’t think I would ever say *“typography error”*, but instead *“typographical error”*.

There is, apparently, [“orthographical” as an near-equivalent form for “spelling”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/239673/5076).

Comment: http://www.ragan.com/Main/Articles/Cut_it_out_Grammar_usage_syntax_are_not_the_same__46273.aspx#idc-cover

Comment: I'm afraid that if this inconsistency bothers you, you are fated to spend a lot of your life being bothered. Language is as it is, not as somebody thinks it ought to be.

Comment: @ColinFine Oh certainly, and I do (by the English language, anyway). Working with much more consistent computer languages every day makes it worse.

Answer (score 4):

"Grammar error" is a compound noun; "grammatical error" is a noun modified by an adjective.  Both are in use, but the latter is preferred in material that can be searched online.